# What is the default sorting order of a OneToMany column in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate I have a class with a List field that has a OneToMany annotation.
What is the default order of this type of field? Is it by ID? or unpredictable?

Comment: The same as you would execute coresponding sql by yourself

Comment: Thanks. And PostgreSQL for example tells there are no guarantees in the ordering/sorting.

Comment: so that is your answer in general. You can always use orderBy on joined assosciation to get desired order, but that is rather plain SQL solution and not hibernate related

Comment: Yes, thank you antoniossss